# Primefaces selectOneMenu not displayed correctly

Tags: java, css, jsf, select, primefaces

I'm using Chrome and I'm getting a weird display for the primefaces p:selectOneMenu:

[image]

And sometimes it is shown correctly like this:

[image]

I couldn't find any css rule to override, any one faced this before?

Comment: Please specify the primefaces version, also write down code for the same

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css file:

```
.ui-selectonemenu-label{
    width:100% !important;
}

.ui-selectonemenu{
    width:100% !important;
}
```